# MYSQLi SELECT Fetch Object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
    if ( isset($_POST['update']) ){
    $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","****","****","****");
    $lasttime = isset($_POST['timestamp']) ? $_POST['timestamp'] : 0;
    while (1){
        sleep(1);
        clearstatcache();
        $mresult = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM tblchat WHERE msg_datetime > $lasttime");
        if (!empty($mresult)){ break; }
    }
    $msgs = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object( $mresult )) { $msgs[] = $row; }
    mysqli_free_result($mresult);
    $response = array();
    $response['msgs'] = $msgs;
    echo json_encode($response);
    flush();
    mysqli_close($db);
    exit();
    }
```

The code is the server for a long polling connection with client. If update is requested, the while loops check for any new messages received after the timestamp sent with the update request. If found, it puts the result in an array and echo it back to the client. 
The resulting output is something like this `[msgs:[{msg_from:"",msg_to:"",msg:"",msg_datetime:""},{msg_from:"",msg_to:"",msg:"",msg_datetime:""}]]`

The code works fine for the first time and send all the recent messages well encapsulated but then it again sends an empty array of messages. Please guide me.

Comment: Its nice to see people migrating to MySQLi or PDO, and yet they keep injecting their variable directly on the query instead of properly using prepared statements ;(

Comment: could you please just rewrite the two queries in my code correctly, i want to learn once for ever how to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: A prepared statement looks like this: `$myquery = 'SELECT field FROM table WHERE field=?';`  For SELECT statements, I typically initialize a statment, prepare the query, bind parameters to it (where the ? marks are), execute the query, store the result and assign the num_rows from the statement to a variable, bind the result to a variable, fetch the result, and finally close the statement.

Comment: I don't understand what's going wrong with your code though.  Please offer a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue with **mysqli_num_rows**

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($mresult)){ $msgs = array(); while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object( $mresult )) { $msgs[] = $row; } mysqli_free_result($mresult); break; }
if (mysqli_num_rows($wresult)){ $writers = array(); while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object( $wresult )) { $writers[] = $row; } mysqli_free_result($wresult); break; }
```

thanks everyone for their help!